# Lucene for multiple server scenario

Tags: content-search, lucene

I have been told that when there are load balancers and multiple servers, lucene will not work.

Is there an alternative that we can still use Lucene as the search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have read that Solr is a better solution, but Lucene does work. You will have indexes on all your servers though.

More info on a similar question here: [How to maintain Sitecore Lucene Indexes in a huge content delivery web farm?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-maintain-sitecore-lucene-indexes-in-a-huge-content-delivery-web-farm/1480)

Answer (score 1):

Lucene does work. You will get separate copy of indexes on all your severs and they would be updated seprately on each server.

There are alternatives:

- Solr or Solr Cloud,
- Coveo,
- Azure Search

Comment: By Separate copy of indexes, you mean we have to manually/programatically copy the files to all the servers. In that case, the main instance should be shut down is it right?

Comment: You don't need to do that manually (although that is done sometimes at first setup) - but if you do, the instances must be stopped indeed.

Comment: If i had to do them programmatically will it work. Wont the indexes be locked, when I do copy?

Comment: By separate copy of indexes I mean that each server will maintain indexes for itself. There is folder where indexes are stored on disk and each server has it's own folder. So when you do a publish from CM to CD, each CD server would have to update own copy of indexes.